# How much RAM is available for Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, memory, microsoft-excel-2010

How can I see how much RAM is available for Excel ?

I am using Excel 2010 Windows (32-bit) NT 6.02 Release:14.0

I know my laptop has 4GB of RAM, but I have been told Excel 32 bit will only be able to use 2GB of this.

Comment: newer versions of excel can make use of 4GB with a patch, but 2010 does not support `LARGEADDRESSAWARE`, so its limited to 2GB. Also note, that windows will not run well if excel is using significant percentages of RAM, and will starve the OS in your scenario, so the 2GB limit probably isn't hurting you much.

Comment: @FrankThomas  I was offered by IT this morning to have my RAM doubled, will 2010 64 bit allow me to use more RAM ?

Comment: yup, but it suprises me that they don't want you to have a newer version, for security if nothing else.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Choose-between-the-64-bit-or-32-bit-version-of-Office-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Excel 2010, 2013 and 2016 are available in 2 versions: 32-bit (2
> Gigabytes of virtual memory)

[Out of Memory, Memory Limits, Memory Leaks, Excel will not start.](http://www.decisionmodels.com/memlimitsc.htm)

> How can I see how much RAM is available for Excel?

Task Manager will indicate how much memory Excel is using.

> On the other hand, the 32-bit edition of Office is limited to 2 GB of
> virtual address space, and this space is shared by Excel, the
> workbook, and add-ins that run in the same process. (Worksheets
> smaller than 2 GB on disk might still contain enough data to occupy 2
> GB or more of addressable memory.)

Additionally,

> The 2-GB limitation is per windows process instance of Excel. You can
> run multiple files in one instance. However, if the files are really
> large and have to be open, consider opening multiple instances for the
> other files. For information about limits that you may encounter, go
> to the following website:

[Memory usage in the 32-bit edition of Excel 2013 and 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3066990/memory-usage-in-the-32-bit-edition-of-excel-2013-and-2016)

Additionally,

> 32-bit versions of Microsoft Excel 2013 and Excel 2016 can take
> advantage of Large Address Aware (LAA) functionality after
> installation of the latest updates. (see the "Resolution" section)
> This change lets 32-bit installations of Excel 2016 consume double the
> memory when users work on a 64-bit Windows OS. The system provides
> this capability by increasing the user mode virtual memory from 2
> gigabytes (GB) to 4 GB. This change provides 50 percent more memory
> (for example, from 2 GB to 3 GB) when users work on a 32-bit system.
>
> [image]

Additionally,

> If you're running 64-bit Windows, this change is applied
> automatically. No action by you is required. The available memory for
> the Excel process is automatically doubled from 2 GB to 4 GB. This
> improves support for actions that use lots of memory.

[Large Address Aware capability change for Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3160741/large-address-aware-capability-change-for-excel)